# How to generate linked group join button

Tags: linkedin-api, jsapi

Does anyone knows how to generate linkedin group button? What i want to do is to display the list of groups that the user joined in.

Like this:

```
Group 1     <button> join </button>
Group 2     <button> join </button>
Group 3     <button> join </button>
```

I don't understand the documentation of group API,https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#membergroups. 
How do i PUT / POST  in JSAPI? and how how do format the post data? Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Updates....

## Is this possible in JS API?

JSAPI different methods can be found here. https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapiraw

I tried the script below and it didn't work.

```
var grp = {
        "group-membership": {
                "group": {
                    "id": 11234555 
                },
                "show-group-logo-in-profile": true,
                "email-digest-frequency": {
                    "code": "daily"
                },
                "email-announcements-from-managers": true,
                "allow-messages-from-members": true,
                "email-for-every-new-post": false,
                "membership-state": {
                    "code": "member"
                }
            }
    }


IN.API.Raw('/people/~/group-memberships').method('POST').body(JSON.stringify(grp)).result(function(a){
    console.log(a);
});
```

Response:

```
  {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Invalid xml {Expected elements 'group@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 membership-state@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 contact-email@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 show-group-logo-in-profile@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 allow-messages-from-members@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 email-digest-frequency@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 email-announcements-from-managers@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 email-for-every-new-post@http://api.linkedin.com/v1' instead of 'group-membership@http://api.linkedin.com/v1' here in element group-membership@http://api.linkedin.com/v1}",
  "requestId": "5FX3EI2PEU",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1395909893090
}
```

### Using XML

```
xmlbody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <group-membership>  <group>
     <id>G11234555</id>   </group>    <show-group-logo-in-profile>true</show-group-logo-in-profile> <email-digest-frequency>
     <code>daily</code>    </email-digest-frequency>    <email-announcements-from-managers>true</email-announcements-from-managers> <allow-messages-from-members>true</allow-messages-from-members>  <email-for-every-new-post>false</email-for-every-new-post>  <membership-state>
     <code>member</code>    </membership-state>  </group-membership> ';
                 IN.API.Raw('/people/~/group-memberships').method('POST').body(xmlbody).result(function(a){ console.log(a);     });
```

Response:

> {   "errorCode": 0,   "message": "Couldn't parse Json body: Unexpected
>   character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String,
>   array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source:
>   java.io.StringReader@27418295; line: 1, column: 2]",   "requestId":
>   "JFGI4LRP2C",   "status": 400,   "timestamp": 1395970257979 }